# Batch file creation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote the following code on my batch file code

```
if not exist "C:\Windows\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" (
 echo Error: "%TMP%\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" does not exist! )

pause
exit
```

However, it did not run accordingly. I got the following message

```
C:\Users\dod\Desktop>if not exist "C:\Windows\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov"
(echo Error: "C:\Users\dod\AppData\Local\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" does
not exist!  )
Error: "C:\Users\dod\AppData\Local\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" does not ex
ist!

C:\Users\dod\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Does that file exist? What folder does %TMP% point to? What is wrong about that output, because it looks OK to me.

Comment: That file does not exist. I was trying to get the message ""C:\Users\dod\AppData\Local\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" does not exist. I don't want to see the first part "if not exist "C:\Windows\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov"
(echo Error"            I have modified the code as followed; however, it still did not work if not exist "C:\Windows\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" (
 echo Error: "C:\Windows\Temp\web.config.hints.cancer.gov" does not exist! )

pause
exit

Comment: The other part of your issue is that the code of the batch file is being printed to the screen, which is the normal behavior. If you don't want the code of the file printed to the screen, then use something like `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

`%TMP%` and `%TEMP%` both point to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`, not to `C:\Windows\Temp`. You need to write the full path or put it into a variable manually like this:

```
SET folder="C:\Windows\Temp"

...your code...

echo Error: %folder%\web.config.hints.cancer.gov does not exist!
```

Comment: Good catch. I believe he also wants the code of the script not to display in the console, so you could improve your answer by adding information about the arguments required to only print the `ECHO` information to the console window.

Comment: Fantastic....thank you for your info. Echo off did work.